# I am getting 404 error for the angular application hosted on Rancher as docker images

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes, rancher

I have an angular app deployed as Docker image in Rancher. I am facing an issue while loading after deployment

Error in Console:

> GET https:///runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

The application URL I am trying to achieve is `https://<domain>/portal` which I have included in the ngnix configuration file.

Comment: In `index.html`, is the base href relative? `<base href="./" />`

Comment: @prabh yes in index the base heref is relative path <base href="/portal">